# Restore scroll position on back button

Tags: reactjs, react-router, refluxjs

I have a route handler that requests data from a store and then maps over that data to render a list of components. My issue is that when I navigate to another page and then go back, the scroll position is not restored because the components have to be re-rendered. Is there anyway to delay setting the scroll position until the list has rendered, or preserve and restore the state of the rendered components on any sort of navigation?

Answer (score 0):

I would cache that list you are rendering if I could, then the back/scroll should not be an issue.

If you can not cache the list, you can [supply](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/api/create.md) your own `scrollBehavior` in `Router.create` call like this:

```
var router = Router.create({
  routes: routes,
  scrollBehavior: YourScrollBehavior
});
```

Comment: Should I cache it in session storage or is there a more react way of doing it?

Comment: I am not *flux expert, but I doubt there is out of the box react/flux solution.

Comment: yea just cache it in sessionStorage or localStorage. whatever man. it's a wild west righ tnow

Answer (score 0):

You can use [willTransitionTo](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/api/components/RouteHandler.md#willtransitiontotransition-params-query-callback) handler on your component to delay route transition until you asynchronously fetch the data from API. That way router can restore the correct scroll possition because the component is instantly rendered with all data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about just making the views `display: none`?

Serialize all the `<divs/>` with an id attribute, and keep an array that maintains history whenever you make them `display: none`.

Now, when a use goes back in history, access this object and reveal that old div again.

This solution allows you to avoid re-rendering components again, and it also makes the browser fast because DOM nodes that are `display: none` don't impact browser performance.

```
var divHistory = [
  {id: 'qwer', scrollPosition: 30},
  {id: 'poiu', scrollPosition: 102},
  {id: 'asdf', scrollPosition: 0},
  {id: 'lkj', scrollPosition: 0},
  {id: 'zxcv', scrollPosition: 4050}
]
```